# how to integrate facebook invite to app on ios other than make Graph api request by myself?

Tags: ios, facebook

I've integrate facebook invite to my adroid app,with RequestsDialogBuilder as what [facebook doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests/?locale=zh_CN) said.After read their doc thoroughly for  several times,I haven't found the coresponding doc about ios.And there are also docs about facebook share.How about facebook-invte?
I also found [ios Sample on github](https://github.com/facebookarchive/ios-howtos).
But neither do i found sample about invite~
Maybe I have to call Graph api.

Answer (score 0):

For inviting users you can use the following code after adding the facebook-sdk

```
[FBWebDialogs
      presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:sharedFacebookHelper.session
      message:@"Your invite message"
      title:nil
      parameters:nil
      handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                              if (error) {
                                                  // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                                  // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                                  NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
                                              } else {
                                                  if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                      // User canceled.
                                                      NSLog(@"User cancelled.");
                                                  } else {
                                                      // Handle the publish feed callback




                                                      } 

                                            }


}];
```

Comment: Thanks.@サンディープ.You saved my life!! According to ur tips,I found the doc about ios sdk request,just by search   "presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession":   _https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.2?locale=zh_CN._